# Elasticsearch use filter on index only when index has field

Tags: elasticsearch

There are 2 indexes: `categories`, `posts`.

**categories**

- name
- body

**posts**

- name
- body
- publish_at
- publish_until

I want to do a query on both indexes with a filter on `publish_at` and `publish_until` for the `posts` index.

`http://localhost:9200/categories,posts/_search`

```
{
      "query": {
          "bool": {
              "must": {
                  "multi_match": {
                      "query": "keyword",
                      "fields": [
                          "name^3",
                          "body"
                      ]
                  }
            },
            "filter": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        { 
                            "range": {
                                "publish_at": {
                                    "lte" : "now"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        { 
                            "range": {
                                "publish_until": {
                                    "gt" : "now"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This query only gives me `posts` as results. I also want `categories` in my results.

How do I apply the date range filters to only indexes with `publish_at` and `publish_until` fields and skip the date range filters for the other indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after a day of fiddling with `bool` I got it working:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "keyword",
                        "fields": [
                            "name^3",
                            "body"
                        ]
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                             "range": {
                                                "publish_at": {
                                                    "lte" : "now"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "range": {
                                                "publish_until": {
                                                    "gt" : "now"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must_not": [
                                        {
                                            "exists": {
                                                "field": "publish_at"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "exists": {
                                                "field": "publish_until"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```